# JS Filtering array of objects by another arrrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, filter

I have three arrays of objects:

```
const names = [
  { value: "Time" },
  { value: "Angle" },
  { value: "Speed" },
  { value: "Mass" }
];

const params = [
  { name: "Time", value: "s" },
  { name: "Time", value: "h" },
  { name: "Time", value: "m" },
  { name: "Angle", value: "rad" },
  { name: "Angle", value: "grade" }
];

const selected = [
  { id: 1, name: "Time", param: "s" },
  { id: 2, name: "Time", param: "h" },
  { id: 3, name: "Time", param: "m" },
  { id: 4, name: "Angle", param: "grade" },
  { id: 5, name: "Speed", param: null }
];
```

I need new names array without items that:

- have been selected with all possible params
- if given name does not have param possible it can bo selected only once

in this case my expected output should be

```
    const expected = [
      { value: "Angle" }, 
      { value: "Mass" }
    ]
```

Comment: Why not use `selected: true|false` flags in all of them and then just use `Array.prototype.filter(...)` to filter them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter by

- not having some value with param `null` and
- not having equal length of the filterd params and selected items and having a length.

```js
const
    names = [{ value: "Time" }, { value: "Angle" }, { value: "Speed" }, { value: "Mass" }],
    params = [{ name: "Time", value: "s" }, { name: "Time", value: "h" }, { name: "Time", value: "m" }, { name: "Angle", value: "rad" }, { name: "Angle", value: "grade" }],
    selected = [ { id: 1, name: "Time", param: "s" }, { id: 2, name: "Time", param: "h" }, { id: 3, name: "Time", param: "m" }, { id: 4, name: "Angle", param: "grade" }, { id: 5, name: "Speed", param: null }],
    result = names.filter(({ value }) => {
        const check = ({ name }) => name === value,
              pl = params.filter(check).length,
              sl = selected.filter(check).length;
  
        return !selected.some(o => o.name === value && o.param === null)
            && !(pl === sl && pl);
    });

console.log(result);
```